# How to solve field error in django models file

Tags: python, html, css, django, postgresql

I have been working on an ecommerce website, the models were previously working fine until i added a new app with  a new customer model but had a different name, though it used the user model, i deleted the app since it really didn't matter. But after deleting, am trying to login, signup, and register but it keeps bringing the error..

Traceback error

```
FieldError at /profile/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: admin, auth_token, customer, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, notifications, password, user_permissions, username
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile/
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: admin, auth_token, customer, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, notifications, password, user_permissions, username
Exception Location: C:\Users\Vernon\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py, line 1709, in names_to_path
Raised during:  ecomapp.views.CustomerProfileView
C:\Users\Vernon\Desktop\django-ecommerce-project-latest\ecomapp\views.py, line 373, in dispatch
        if request.user.is_authenticated and Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists(): …
Local vars
Variable    Value
__class__   
<class 'ecomapp.views.CustomerProfileView'>
args    
()
kwargs  
{}
request 
<WSGIRequest: GET '/profile/'>
self    
<ecomapp.views.CustomerProfileView object at 0x0000016086F276D0>
```

```
models.py
```

```
    
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    # for the csv
    import csv
    from django.http import HttpResponse
    import datetime
    
    
    # working with the csv files
    class ExportCsvMixin:
        def export_as_csv(self, request, queryset):
            meta = self.model._meta
            field_names = [field.name for field in meta.fields]
            response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}.csv'.format(meta)
            writer = csv.writer(response)
            writer.writerow(field_names)
            for obj in queryset:
                row = writer.writerow([getattr(obj, field) for field in
                field_names])
            return response
        export_as_csv.short_description = "Export Selected"
    
    
    class Admin(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="admins")
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
    
    
    class Customer(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
        joined_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        actions = ["export_as_csv"]
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.full_name
    
    
    class Category(models.Model, ExportCsvMixin):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        actions = ["export_as_csv"]
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'categories'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
    
    
    class Product(models.Model, ExportCsvMixin):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
        category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products")
        marked_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        selling_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        description = models.TextField()
        in_stock = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="Fully stocked")
        warranty = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
        return_policy = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
        view_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        actions = ["export_as_csv"]
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
    
    
    class ProductImage(models.Model):
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to="products/images/")
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.product.title
    
    
    class Cart(models.Model):
        customer = models.ForeignKey(
            Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
        total = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return "Cart: " + str(self.id)
    
    
    class CartProduct(models.Model):
        cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        rate = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        subtotal = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return "Cart: " + str(self.cart.id) + " CartProduct: " + str(self.id)
    
    
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ("Order Received", "Order Received"),
        ("Order Processing", "Order Processing"),
        ("On the way", "On the way"),
        ("Order Completed", "Order Completed"),
        ("Order Canceled", "Order Canceled"),
    )
    
    METHOD = (
        ("Cash On Delivery", "Cash On Delivery"),
        ("Khalti", "Khalti"),
        ("Esewa", "Esewa"),
    )
    
    
    class Order(models.Model, ExportCsvMixin):
        cart = models.OneToOneField(Cart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        ordered_by = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
        subtotal = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        discount = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        total = models.PositiveIntegerField()
        order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ORDER_STATUS)
        created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        payment_method = models.CharField(
            max_length=20, choices=METHOD, default="Cash On Delivery")
        payment_completed = models.BooleanField(
            default=False, null=True, blank=True)
        actions = ["export_as_csv"]
    
        def __str__(self):
            return f" Order:{str(self.id)} : {self.mobile} "
```

```
views.py
```

````
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, CreateView, FormView, DetailView, ListView
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator
    from .utils import password_reset_token
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db.models import Q
    from .models import *
    from .forms import *
    import requests
    from webcontent.models import *
    from webcontent.models import Subscribers
    # the api imports 
    from rest_framework.decorators  import api_view
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from ecomproject.serializers import *
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
    from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    

    
    
    class HomeView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "home.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['myname'] = "vernonthedev"
            all_products = Product.objects.all().order_by("-id")
            paginator = Paginator(all_products, 8)
            page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
            print(page_number)
            product_list = paginator.get_page(page_number)
            context['product_list'] = product_list
            return context
    
    
    
    class AllProductsView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication,]
    
        template_name = "allproducts.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['allcategories'] = Category.objects.all()
            return context
    
    
    class ProductDetailView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "productdetail.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            url_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
            product = Product.objects.get(slug=url_slug)
            product.view_count += 1
            product.save()
            context['product'] = product
            return context
    
    
   
    class CustomerRegistrationView(CreateView):
        template_name = "customerregistration.html"
        form_class = CustomerRegistrationForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy("ecomapp:home")
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            form.instance.user = user
            login(self.request, user)
            return super().form_valid(form)
    
        def get_success_url(self):
            if "next" in self.request.GET:
                next_url = self.request.GET.get("next")
                return next_url
            else:
                return self.success_url
    
    
    class CustomerLogoutView(View):
        def get(self, request):
            logout(request)
            return redirect("ecomapp:home")
    
    
    class CustomerLoginView(FormView):
        template_name = "customerlogin.html"
        form_class = CustomerLoginForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy("ecomapp:home")
    
        # form_valid method is a type of post method and is available in createview formview and updateview
        def form_valid(self, form):
            uname = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            pword = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            usr = authenticate(username=uname, password=pword)
            if usr is not None and Customer.objects.filter(user=usr).exists():
                login(self.request, usr)
            else:
                return render(self.request, self.template_name, {"form": self.form_class, "error": "Invalid credentials"})
    
            return super().form_valid(form)
    
        def get_success_url(self):
            if "next" in self.request.GET:
                next_url = self.request.GET.get("next")
                return next_url
            else:
                return self.success_url

        
    
    class ContactView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "contactus.html"
    
    
    class CustomerProfileView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "customerprofile.html"
    
        def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated and Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
                pass
            else:
                return redirect("/login/?next=/profile/")
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            customer = self.request.user.customer
            context['customer'] = customer
            orders = Order.objects.filter(cart__customer=customer).order_by("-id")
            context["orders"] = orders
            return context
    
    

    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    # working with the django rest framework api
    class GetRoutesView(APIView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication,]
        def get(self, request):
            routes = [
                'GET /api/',
                'GET /api/products',
                'GET /api/products/:id',
    
            ]
            return Response(routes)
    
    # it will only display items for only an authenticated user and must provide his 
    # details
    class ProductsView(APIView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication,]
        def get(self, request):
            products = Product.objects.all()
            data = []
            serializer = ProductSerializer(products, many=True)
            for product in serializer.data:
                fab_query = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).filter(
                    user_id = product['id']
                    )
                
                
            return Response(serializer.data)
    
    
    
    # class based api view for one product
    class ProductView(APIView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication,]
    
        def get(self, request, pk):
            product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)
            serializer = ProductSerializer(product, many=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
    
    # register a new user when they register using the app
    class RegisterView(APIView):
        def post(self, request):
            serializers = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializers.is_valid():
                serializers.save()
                return Resp`enter code here`onse({"error":False})
            return Response({"error":True})
    
    ```
    views.py
    ```from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView, CreateView, FormView, DetailView, ListView
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.urls import reverse_lazy, reverse
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator
    from .utils import password_reset_token
    from django.core.mail import send_mail
    from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.db.models import Q
    from .models import *
    from .forms import *
    import requests
    from webcontent.models import *
    from webcontent.models import Subscribers
    # the api imports 
    from rest_framework.decorators  import api_view
    from rest_framework.response import Response
    from ecomproject.serializers import *
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
    from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
    from rest_framework.views import APIView
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    
    
    class EcomMixin(object):
        def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id")
            if cart_id:
                cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
                if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.customer:
                    cart_obj.customer = request.user.customer
                    cart_obj.save()
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    
    class HomeView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "home.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['myname'] = "vernonthedev"
            all_products = Product.objects.all().order_by("-id")
            paginator = Paginator(all_products, 8)
            page_number = self.request.GET.get('page')
            print(page_number)
            product_list = paginator.get_page(page_number)
            context['product_list'] = product_list
            return context
    
    
    
    class AllProductsView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication,]
    
        template_name = "allproducts.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['allcategories'] = Category.objects.all()
            return context
    
    
    class ProductDetailView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "productdetail.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            url_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
            product = Product.objects.get(slug=url_slug)
            product.view_count += 1
            product.save()
            context['product'] = product
            return context
    
    
    class AddToCartView(EcomMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name = "addtocart.html"
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            # get product id from requested url
            product_id = self.kwargs['pro_id']
            # get product
            product_obj = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    
            # check if cart exists
            cart_id = self.request.session.get("cart_id", None)
            if cart_id:
                cart_obj = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
                this_product_in_cart = cart_obj.cartproduct_set.filter(
                    product=product_obj)
    
                # item already exists in cart
                if this_product_in_cart.exists():
                    cartproduct = this_product_in_cart.last()
                    cartproduct.quantity += 1
                    cartproduct.subtotal += product_obj.selling_price
                    cartproduct.save()
                    cart_obj.total += product_obj.selling_price
                    cart_obj.save()
                # new item is added in cart
                else:
                    cartproduct = CartProduct.objects.create(
                        cart=cart_obj, product=product_obj, rate=product_obj.selling_price, quantity=1, subtotal=product_obj.selling_price)
                    cart_obj.total += product_obj.selling_price
                    cart_obj.save()
    
            else:
                cart_obj = Cart.objects.create(total=0)
                self.request.session['cart_id'] = cart_obj.id
                cartproduct = CartProduct.objects.create(
                    cart=cart_obj, product=product_obj, rate=product_obj.selling_price, quantity=1, subtotal=product_obj.selling_price)
                cart_obj.total += product_obj.selling_price
                cart_obj.save()
    
            return context
    
    
    class ManageCartView(EcomMixin, View):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            cp_id = self.kwargs["cp_id"]
            action = request.GET.get("action")
            cp_obj = CartProduct.objects.get(id=cp_id)
            cart_obj = cp_obj.cart
    
            if action == "inc":
                cp_obj.quantity += 1
                cp_obj.subtotal += cp_obj.rate
                cp_obj.save()
                cart_obj.total += cp_obj.rate
                cart_obj.save()
            elif action == "dcr":
                cp_obj.quantity -= 1
                cp_obj.subtotal -= cp_obj.rate
                cp_obj.save()
                cart_obj.total -= cp_obj.rate
                cart_obj.save()
                if cp_obj.quantity == 0:
                    cp_obj.delete()
    
            elif action == "rmv":
                cart_obj.total -= cp_obj.subtotal
                cart_obj.save()
                cp_obj.delete()
            else:
                pass
            return redirect("ecomapp:mycart")
    
    
    class EmptyCartView(EcomMixin, View):
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            cart_id = request.session.get("cart_id", None)
            if cart_id:
                cart = Cart.objects.get(id=cart_id)
                cart.cartproduct_set.all().delete()
                cart.total = 0
                cart.save()
            return redirect("ecomapp:mycart")
    
   
 
    
    
    class CustomerRegistrationView(CreateView):
        template_name = "customerregistration.html"
        form_class = CustomerRegistrationForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy("ecomapp:home")
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            username = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            password = form.cleaned_data.get("password")
            email = form.cleaned_data.get("email")
            user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
            form.instance.user = user
            login(self.request, user)
            return super().form_valid(form)
    
        def get_success_url(self):
            if "next" in self.request.GET:
                next_url = self.request.GET.get("next")
                return next_url
            else:
                return self.success_url
    
    
    class CustomerLogoutView(View):
        def get(self, request):
            logout(request)
            return redirect("ecomapp:home")
    
    
    class CustomerLoginView(FormView):
        template_name = "customerlogin.html"
        form_class = CustomerLoginForm
        success_url = reverse_lazy("ecomapp:home")
    
        # form_valid method is a type of post method and is available in createview formview and updateview
        def form_valid(self, form):
            uname = form.cleaned_data.get("username")
            pword = form.cleaned_data["password"]
            usr = authenticate(username=uname, password=pword)
            if usr is not None and Customer.objects.filter(user=usr).exists():
                login(self.request, usr)
            else:
                return render(self.request, self.template_name, {"form": self.form_class, "error": "Invalid credentials"})
    
            return super().form_valid(form)
    
        def get_success_url(self):
            if "next" in self.request.GET:
                next_url = self.request.GET.get("next")
                return next_url
            else:
                return self.success_url
    
    
    
    class CustomerProfileView(TemplateView):
        template_name = "customerprofile.html"
    
        def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated and Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
                pass
            else:
                return redirect("/login/?next=/profile/")
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            customer = self.request.user.customer
            context['customer'] = customer
            orders = Order.objects.filter(cart__customer=customer).order_by("-id")
            context["orders"] = orders
            return context
    
    
    class CustomerOrderDetailView(DetailView):
        template_name = "customerorderdetail.html"
        model = Order
        context_object_name = "ord_obj"
    
        def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.is_authenticated and Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).exists():
                order_id = self.kwargs["pk"]
                order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
                if request.user.customer != order.cart.customer:
                    return redirect("ecomapp:customerprofile")
            else:
                return redirect("/login/?next=/profile/")
            return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    
    
  
    
    
 
    
    # register a new user when they register using the app
    class RegisterView(APIView):
        def post(self, request):
            serializers = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializers.is_valid():
                serializers.save()
                return Response({"error":False})
            return Response({"error":True})
````

serializers.py (creates a new user on post request)

```
    
    from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer
    from ecomapp.models import Product, Customer
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
    from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
    
    # create a new user when we get a post request
    Customer = get_user_model()
    
    class UserSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Customer
            fields = ('id', 'username', 'password', 'email',)
            extra_kwargs = {'password':{"write_only":True, 'required':True}}
    
        def create(self, validated_data):
            user = Customer.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
            Token.objects.create(customer=user)
            return user
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I was using django rest api to make the api calls to the site, the conflict mostly came when i had created a new app that had a new user model but with a different name. I deleted it hoping to solve the problem but it didn't

Comment: this is the error: Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: admin, auth_token, customer, date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, notifications, password, user_permissions, username

Comment: Please include the full traceback error in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: You got this error because you have taken in-built user. Inbuilt user can acess only username, password1, password2. You cannot add extra fields

Comment: howt should i over come this issue then

Comment: because i also got to know that the main issue comes when i use an api to register a new user then after when i come to the website, the user account system cant function

Answer (score 0):

Django inbuilt user model only has access to username, password, email..So make sure in the serializers.py file, you are using the required fields not the customized fields because you cannot customise django user model(get_user_model()).
Make sure you use the required fields not the fields outside the scope of django user model..